# Unknown warning in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When ever i run my application in development mode i get this warning message

> Started GET "/assets/playerbg.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-07 03:30:53 -0500
>
> Served asset /playerbg.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
>
> [2012-01-07 03:30:53] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

please how can i go about this message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "WARN Could not determine content-length of response body." mean and how to I get rid of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082364/what-does-warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-mean-and-h)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an issue with Webrick and ruby 1.9.3. Nothing to worry about.

If you use [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), you won't see this warning.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue. After adding entry 
 `gem "webrick", "1.3.1"`  to my Gemfile for development mode solved my issue.

You can refer [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612618/warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-set-content-length-of) for more help.

Comment: Nice. I have figured out a way to prevent this lately by using the quiet_asset gem

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a few things with webrick and reverting to 1.3.1 is the first occasion that the error message has not been displaying.