# WARN Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “WARN Could not determine content-length of response body.” mean and how to I get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082364/what-does-warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-mean-and-h)

I just upgraded to rails 3.2.2, and now on rails s, page load, I get all these errors in the log:

```
[2012-03-07 19:46:14] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2012-03-07 19:46:14] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Per previous SO threads, I tried the following:

**/config/application.rb**

```
config.assets.logger = false
config.assets.logger = nil
```

None of these worked. Any ideas on how to disable this logging for this error? Or to fix the issue :)

Thanks

Comment: While it may be a duplicate, it does need to grab the rails team attention as it's been over 6 months, and a new version since they acknowledged they needed to clean it up, and yet they still havent.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This is a problem of Webrick.
you can use "Thin" instead.

Add this to Gemfile

```
gem 'thin'
```

then `rails s` will use thin instead of Webrick, and the warn will disappear.

Comment: In your config/environmenst/development.rb, add this line: 

    config.middleware.use Rails::Rack::LogTailer

Comment: @cam song: almost correct: `rails s thin` will use thin instead of Webrick, and the warn will disappear.

Comment: I second using thin instead of WEBrick. However. On Windows the install of the thin dependencies (more specifically the eventmachine) may be problematic. I use the following in my Gemfile to get a clean install of thin: `gem 'eventmachine', '1.0.0.rc.4', :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]`. **Note**: I installed Rails via the [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) which includes the [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit). Might not work without it(?).

Comment: On Rails 3.2 and above `rails s` will use thin if it exists in the Gemfile.

Comment: doesn't work. `puma` worked

Answer (score 28):

Patch mentioned by Amiel Martin works for me! Just find your webrick path (ex., **c:\Ruby\lib\ruby\1.9.1\webrick**\  on Windows) and change **httpresponse.rb** file as described in https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/2300/204_304_keep_alive.patch

And don't forget restart Webrick!

Comment: I explicitly added version 1.3.1 of WEBrick to my gemfile and this solved the problem.

Comment: Strange:  According to the message that displays when I run `rails s`, I was already using WEBrick 1.3.1 (with Rails 3.2.8), but I was still getting the warning messages. I added `gem 'webrick', '1.3.1'` to my gemfile and the warnings stopped. A different version of 1.3.1?

Comment: This did NOT fix it for me, perhaps because I am using RVM.  wasn't sure where to make this change with RVM.  However putting `gem 'webrick', '1.3.1'` in my Gemfile and `bundle install` and restart server worked for me and removed the message.

Answer (score 9):

This patch for WEBrick is also reported to work:

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/2300/204_304_keep_alive.patch