# WARN Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have imported a existing project of Ruby on Rails, to start application i did

```
Buldle install
rails server
```

I got server running, when i launch localhost:3000 it should open my root page. But i am getting following error:

> Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 17.0ms)
>   [2013-08-05 11:52:36] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

please, let me know if i am missing anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WARN Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612618/warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-set-content-length-of)

Comment: The other SO question will address the warning, but that is unlikely to be related to why you're not seeing your root page.

Comment: @sushithle - i tried solution mention on this page but still unable to see content.

Comment: you should check in your routes file which layout is rendered and if the layout file actually does render something but a blank page.

Comment: You should first remove the public/index.html and set a root path in config/routes.rb like this: `root to: 'home#index'`, then restart the server, clear you browser cache and try again. Hope this helps.

Comment: got it working, it was due to JS missing file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "WARN Could not determine content-length of response body." mean and how to I get rid of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082364/what-does-warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-mean-and-h)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it by adding gem 'thin' in Gemfile, then running the command bundle and starting the server with 'rails server' command.