# Ruby on Rails warn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “WARN Could not determine content-length of response body.” mean and how to I get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082364/what-does-warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-mean-and-h)

> [2012-03-20 14:31:57] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Who can explain what this is for warn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood correctly its nothing to worry about it gets removed by the Rails-Core's members.

As Jipiboily already said:

> Duplicate
>   of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082364/what-does-warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-mean-and-h

cheers