# Ruby on Rails: (Beginner) How can I make my style sheet (in public/stylesheet folder) be used by my layouts?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm learning Ruby on Rails (sorry for the newb question, I couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow), and I am having an issue with my app using the stylesheet that was assigned to the application.

I put a simple css style (A colored body tag) into my public/stylesheets directory called "application.css"

in my "app" I have the stylesheet called via:
"<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application" %>"

When I reload my page (which has no body css style specified in it, only pure simple html), I see no change.  What am I doing wrong?

---

I've tried to reset the server, I've inspected the code of the rendered page and see nothing glaring...  What am I missing?

The only ruby on rails warning that I get when the page opens is "Warn: could not determine content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true", which seems to be ignorable -->  [What does "WARN Could not determine content-length of response body." mean and how to I get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082364/what-does-warn-could-not-determine-content-length-of-response-body-mean-and-h)

thanks

Comment: Yes, you can safely ignore that content-length message, it has nothing to do with your stylesheet problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in `app/assets/stylesheets`

You should really do a tutorial or two on Rails before you jump in. It is a very opinionated framework and it does a lot for you automatically. If you don't know what it's doing for you automatically and where things go, you'll encounter a ton of problems like this.

I'd highly, highly recommend Michael Hartl's free tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book